# Different checkout pages on multistore

Tags: checkout, multistore

I have to add some third party code to the checkout page `success.phtml` in order to let our customer receive a feedback request once the order is confirmed. The problem is that we have a multistore setup and I want that the feedback request is working only for one store and not all. We have different template for each store but I see that we have only one `success.phtml` page in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout` so I don't know how to filter the order from just one store. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different themes per store view, then you should be able to copy the /template/checkout/success.phtml from the parent theme into the second store view's theme and edit the one you need.

Magento's themes "cascade" so that if a file is missing from a theme magento will just look in the parent of that theme for the file and continue doing that until it reaches the base/default theme.

To find out the parent of your theme, look in THEME/etc/theme.xml for the parent xml tag.